# Uncaught ReferenceError: phone is not defined javascript error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I am a clicking on Phone number it displaying me that. This function is defined. How can I resolve following error and thanks in advance!

Below is given my code:

```
<div class="product-label">
    <h4><?php echo $p["FullName"];?>, <?php echo $p["Area"];?></h4>
    <h5 style="font-size:14px"><span class="icon-calendar"></span>  <?php echo $p["SaleDate"];?></h5>
    <h5 style="font-size:14px"><span class="icon-clock"></span>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($p['StartTime']); $i++):?>
      <?php echo $p['StartTime'][$i].'-'.$p['EndTime'][$i]?>
    <?php endfor;?>
    </h5>
    <div data-balloon-length="fit" data-balloon=" <?php echo $p["Address1"].'-'.$p["Postal"];?>" data-balloon-pos="up">
        <h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
            <span class="icon-home"></span>  
            <?php echo $p["Address1"].'-'.$p["Postal"];?>
        </h5>
    </div>
    <div data-balloon-length="fit" data-balloon=" <?php echo $p["description"];?>" data-balloon-pos="up">
        <h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
            <span class="icon-file"></span>  
            <?php echo $p["description"];?>
        </h5>
    </div>
    <h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
        <span class="icon-file"></span>  
        <a onclick="phone(<?php echo $p['checkbox'][0]['UniqueID']?>,this);"  id="thumb<?php echo $p['checkbox'][0]['UniqueID']?>" style="cursor:pointer;color:#000"><u>Phone Number</u></a>
    </h5>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
function phone(id,ths){
    var email = '';

    if(<?=$loggedin?>){
        email = <?php $email;?>;
    }
    else{
        email = $("#cmail").val();
    }

    alert(email);
}
```

Comment: did u means, `$ is not defined`?

Comment: @devpro yes it giving following error in console.

Comment: If your `phone()` function is defined inside a jQuery "ready" block, then it won't be global and you'll get that error. You should be assigning your event handlers with jQuery anyway.

Comment: no it not declared in document ready

Comment: What is the actual error? An example of the rendered HTML (rather than the PHP) would be helpful because it's not clear what the type of `<?php echo $p['checkbox'][0]['UniqueID']?>` is. Also using `onclick` to set an event listener is pretty old school. It would be better to make that a `<button>` and add a `data-phone` attribute that can be retrieved via an event handler that was made with `HTMLElement.addEventListener` or a jQuery equivalent (`$('.thing').on('click', function() { ... });`).

Comment: it just because of `if(<?=$loggedin?>){
              email = <?php $email;?>;
          }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting the error just because of:

```
if(<?=$loggedin?>){
   email = <?php $email;?>;
}
```

Don't know where you define this? `$loggedin` ?

Second, `<?php $email;?>` this will do nothing here.

**Basic Example:**

```js
function phone(id,ths){
    alert(id);
    alert(ths);             
}
```

```html
<a onclick="phone('111',this);" href="javascript:void(0);">Phone Number</a>
```

Also note that, your code is working, if i remove this code block:

```
if(<?=$loggedin?>){
   email = <?php $email;?>;
}
```